# Sencha Touch: searching components with classes with ComponentQuery() and down()

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a problem and don't know if this is a bug or I misunderstood something. I wanted to search for a component with a specific class. Example:

```
Ext.define('Test', {
  xtype: 'Test',
  cls: ['cat', 'dog']
});
```

I wanted to find this component I created in a `Ext.Container` with `this.down('Test[cls~=cat]')` (I used `~=` because the component has multiple classes). But I got `undefined` or `null` (don't know anymore) as a result.

With `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('Test[cls~=cat]')` I actually could find it.

Why is that? I thought `down()` is the same as `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` with the difference that it's search scope is not global.

I am using the current version of Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't work. But you can use

```
this.query('Test[cls~=cat]')
```

or you use something like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.pseudos.hasCls = function(items, cls) {
    var i = 0, l = items.length, c, result = [];
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        var c = items[i];
        if (c._cls && c._cls.indexOf(cls) > -1) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
};
```

and call it like:

```
this.down(".component:hasCls(cat)")
```